# Google Maps: displaying specific marker from external click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a site where there is an index page with a list of locations and a map page that lays them all out visually. I am trying to create an action where I can click on the building location on the index page and the map page will open and display ONLY the marker for that location. With the code I currently have (below), it almost works, but it brings up the marker for the first location every time. Now I am trying to figure out if I can alter my code so that the marker placed corresponds to the correct location. Any advice would be much appreciated :)

relevant INDEX page code:

```
<div id="phil" class="space cub ope food"> 
       <h2>location one</h2>
       <div class="locate" onclick="location.href='map.html'; myclick(0);"><h5><em>mhp 2nd floor</em></h5></div>
</div>

<div id="nann" class="space res gro lou roo caf food soft prnt">
        <h2><a href="ann.html">location five</a></h2>
        <div class="locate" onclick="location.href='map.html'; myclick(4);"><h5><em>ann</em></h5></div>
</div>
```

MAP page code:

```
    <div id="map"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var gmarkers = [];
    var locations = [
      ['<h4><a href="phil.html">location one</a></h4>MHP 2nd floor', 34.01885, -118.286808],
      ['<h4><a href="cc.html">location two</a></h4>TCC 1st floor', 34.020004, -118.286186],
      ['<h4><a href="kort.html">location three</a></h4>STU 311', 34.020246, -118.285924],
      ['<h4><a href="daut.html">location four</a></h4>VPD', 34.019005, -118.283855],
      ['<h4><a href="ann.html">location five</a></h4>ANN (301)', 34.020897, -118.287],
      ['<h4><a href="court.html">location six</a></h4>outside VPD', 34.019075, -118.283811],
      ['<h4><a href="arch.html">location seven</a></h4>WAH basement', 34.019221, -118.287797],
      ['<h4><a href="sea.html">location eight</a></h4>SSL 1st floor', 34.019557, -118.288741],
      ['<h4><a href="salv.html">location nine</a></h4>SAL 125', 34.019666, -118.289578],
      ['<h4><a href="king.html">location ten</a></h4>', 34.024845, -118.287958],
      ['<h4><a href="elli.html">location eleven</a></a></h4>TCC 222', 34.020102, -118.286574],
      ['<h4><a href="vc.html">location twelve</a></h4>VKC basement', 34.021211, -118.283709],
    ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.021622, -118.28633),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map,
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

       gmarkers[ids] = marker;
    }
this.myclick=function(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: I would suggest passing the index to the desired marker in the query string. [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?marker=1)

Answer (score 0):

You use only one marker but you need more.

Try adding an array of marker and not one only this way

```
  var marker = [];
  var i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: map,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
    }
  })(marker, i));
```